# Subtract two Pandas DataFrames joined on multiple column values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to subtract the values of a column in DataFrame A, from the values from a column in DataFrame B, but only if multiple column values are equal to each other.

Assume that (fictionally):

```
DataFrame A:
Index    Department  Speciality   TargetMonth Capacity
1        Sales       Cars         2019-1      150
2        Sales       Cars         2019-2      120
3        Sales       Furniture    2019-1      110
4        IT          Servers      2019-1      100

DataFrame B:
Index    Department  Speciality   TargetMonth Required
1        Sales       Cars         2019-1      100
2        Sales       Cars         2019-2      120
3        IT          Servers      2019-1      50
4        Sales       Furniture    2019-1      50
```

I swapped the order of Index 3 and 4 in DataFrame B compared to A on purpose. My goal is to subtract DataFrame B its Required column as being required capacity hours from DataFrame A's Capacity column and resulting in another, not necessarily required to be sorted, list:

```
Index    Department  Speciality   TargetMonth Result
1        Sales       Cars         2019-1      50
2        Sales       Cars         2019-2      0
3        Sales       Furniture    2019-1      60
4        IT          Servers      2019-1      50
```

So, technically, subtract only, and only if all column values match each other and not based on order, as some rows may be missing in one list or the other.

I could solve this with some for loops and conditions but I suppose there's a clean and neat Pandas way to solve this with .subtract although it's the "joining" part on which I am currently stuck.

Thanks for your time in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is why the `Index` is so useful, subtraction will be aligned on the indices (both rows and columns).

```
dfA = dfA.set_index(['Department', 'Speciality', 'TargetMonth'])
dfB = dfB.set_index(['Department', 'Speciality', 'TargetMonth'])

dfA.sub(dfB.rename(columns={'Required': 'Capacity'}), fill_value=0)

                                   Capacity
Department Speciality TargetMonth          
IT         Servers    2019-1             50
Sales      Cars       2019-1             50
                      2019-2              0
           Furniture  2019-1             60
```

Comment: I went for this answer as this did exactly what I needed and with reset_index() I was able to get the flattened result back. Great stuff!

Comment: Yes it seemed like those 3 levels were a unique key for each table, so this is fairly useful. Things can get odd with a duplicated index, as the subtraction will result in an outer product of the duplicated keys. In those cases, it could perhaps be useful to aggregate prior to the subtraction.

Comment: @ALollz does the same work for sum? `dfA.sum(dfB.rename(columns={'Required': 'Capacity'}), fill_value=0)`

Answer (score 5):

I would use merge with keys:

For this solution taking your dataframe A as dfA & dataframe as dfB

```
   df_result =  pd.merge(dfA, dfB, how='inner', on=['Department','Speciality','TargetMonth'])
```

This will put the dataframes together based on the keys: ['Department','Speciality','TargetMonth'] and will result in a dataframe where the the keys appear in both dataframes (how = 'inner').

I.E.  if there is a key in dfB that is:

```
   {'Department': 'IT','Speciality':'Furniture','TargetMonth':2019-1}
```

This value will not appear in dataframe df_result. More Information can be found here - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

Then the solution using Pandas vectorization:

```
   df_result['Result'] = df_result['Capacity'] - df_result['Required']
```

Comment: I however also did use your merge suggestion just a little later on to normalize and concatenate my results back into a summarizing DataFrame. Thanks for your suggestion as well!