# Multiply two data frames, base on a columns and skipping rows do not fulfill a condition

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index, multiplication

I have two data frames, the first one has two indexes (country and product) and the value of the variable associated. I have 20 countries and 7 products. Note that I can have two rows with the same country and product in this data frame because each row corresponds to a different observation.

df1

```
                                        value
Country     Product 
Guatemala   Hydro                       259.420233
            Oil                         4.211656
            Oil                         341.550360
            Coal, peat and oil shale    4.311316
            Coal, peat and oil shale    NaN
            Hydro                       24.433527
Colombia    Oil                         10
            Coal, peat and oil shale    4.311316

.
.
.
```

The second data frame is EXACTLY like I show below

df2

```
                                        mult
Country     Product 
Argentina   Natural gas                 1
Colombia    Oil                         161
Mexico      Coal, peat and oil shale    9
            Natural gas                 2
```

I am trying to multiply the two data frames. The rows of the final data frame must be equal to the first data frame. When there is not any available value in df2 to multiply the row in df1 (e.g. Guatemala/Oil), the value in df1 must be unchanged.

I really appreciate your help. I have tried many options and any works.

Comment: `df1.multiply(df2.rename(columns={'mult': 'value'}), fill_value=1)`? Perhaps look at the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54540704/subtract-two-pandas-dataframes-joined-on-multiple-column-values. The operation is subtraction but that changes very little, other than maybe wanting to set `fill_value=1`. You even already have the MultiIndex here...

Comment: @ALollz I get this error TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

Comment: I can't reproduce that with your provided data. Does one of your `DataFrame`s have an index level with `NaN`? If so you need to remove that row. before the multiply try: `df1 = df1.reindex(df1.index.dropna())` and the same for df2

Answer (score 0):

First, it’s not a great idea to index on columns that will generate duplicates. If you are really that thirsty to violate that best practice, you can still follow my instructions below and then change it back to the original index.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = df1.reset_index(drop = False)
df2 = df2.reset_index(drop = False)

df3 = df1.merge(df2, on = [‘product’, ‘country’], how = ‘left’)

df3[ ‘result’] = np.where(df3.mult.isnull(), df3.value, df3.value * df3.mult)

#now, disrespect all that is holy
df3 = df3.set_index([‘product’, ‘country])
```